# Post parameters not working in file_get_contents() php

Tags: php, html, email

I had two PHP files on my same server, Where one PHP file is used to send the mail and the other PHP file is what will be the body of the other mail so, I do this like this

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

require_once('connect.php');

$email = $_POST['email'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
print_r($email);
print_r($name);

$postdata = http_build_query(
array(
    'email' => $email,
    'name' => $name
)
);

$opts = array('http' =>
array(
    'method'  => 'POST',
    'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'content' => $postdata
 )
 );

$to=$email;
$subject="Welcome Aboard| Judgement6";
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$email_text = file_get_contents('Judgement6.php',false,$context);

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: Judgement6 fantasy game<xyz@gmail.com>" . "\r\n";


if(mail($to,$subject,$email_text,$headers))
{
echo 'email sent';
}
else{
echo 'email not sent';
}
  }

   ?>
```

Now the problem is that the file is included in the body of my mail but the post parameters never went there and the required variables remain null in the second file...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`file_get_contents()` returns the file in a string as it is, it will not pass any existing variables, for that  you will need to use include or require.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

What you can do is inside Judgement6.php create the variable `$email_text` and then include the file in your script.

Inside Judgement6.php:

```
$mail_text = "ALL THE CONTENT AND $VARIABLES INSIDE Judgement6.php";
```

For example, if Judgement6.php has the following script:

```
Hello <?php echo $name; ?>,
Thank you for subscribing to our <?php echo $_POST['service']; ?> 
on <?php echo date("Y-m-d"); ?>.
```

You will write

```
$mail_text = "Hello  $name,
Thank you for subscribing to our ".$_POST['service']." 
on ".date("Y-m-d").".";
```

Be careful with concatenation and using `"` inside the string, you will need to escape them `\"`

In your file

---

```
$to=$email;
$subject="Welcome Aboard| Judgement6";    
include_once('Judgement6.php');
```

---

or

---

```
$to=$email;
$subject="Welcome Aboard| Judgement6";  
require_once('Judgement6.php');
```

---

Comment: well your answer does send parameters to the Judgement6 file but email body does not contain the html which judgement6 has, mail body only has this line ALL THE CONTENT AND $VARIABLES INSIDE Judgement6.php @multimediaxp

Comment: @VipulSingh I don't know what the content of Judgement6.php, that's why I wrote "ALL THE CONTENT AND $VARIABLES INSIDE Judgement6.php", Obviously you need to keep the content as it is and save it into the variable  $mail_text.

Comment: so you mean I should copy all the HTML inside the parenthesis of $mail_text @multimediaxp, Its a big HTML file...

Comment: @VipulSingh See my answer, I changed it and made it as clear as I can. I hope it helps.

Comment: @VipulSingh And yes, all the content :)

Comment: @VipulSingh I forgot to mention that with this method you don't need $context = stream_context_create($opts);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181859/discussion-between-multimediaxp-and-vipul-singh).

Comment: could anyone help on it, please??