# get content of search result with file_get_content php

Tags: php

is there a possible way to get content of search result by file_get_content. I am trying to do this site's search results.

> http://brillia.com/search/?attribute=1&area=13900,13100,13200,14999,12999,11999

but it's not giving me the content of this part `?attribute=1&area=13900,13100,13200,14999,12999,11999` is it something missing in my function. Or file_get_content is not enough for this?

```
    function pageContent(String $url): \DOMDocument
    {
       $html = cache()->rememberForever($url, function () use ($url) {

           $opts = [
               "http" => [
                   "method" => "GET",
                   "header" => "Accept: text/html\r\n"
               ]
           ];
           $context = stream_context_create($opts);
           $file = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

           return $file;

       });
       $parser = new \DOMDocument();
       libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

       $parser->loadHTML($html = mb_convert_encoding($html,'HTML-ENTITIES', 'ASCII, JIS, UTF-8, EUC-JP, SJIS'));

       return $parser;
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Post parameters not working in file\_get\_contents() php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52808951/post-parameters-not-working-in-file-get-contents-php)

Comment: try to use url_encode first, the comma should be a %2C

Comment: works perfect... do you get any error?

Answer (score 1):

The URL you're using is making another Ajax call, which is:

> http://brillia.com/api/search/?area=13900,13100,13200,14999,12999,11999&key=2CsR0Bzv&mode=1&attribute=1&area=13900%2C13100%2C13200%2C14999%2C12999%2C11999&_=1552729056711

This will give you the desired result.

Comment: why do you want to parse Ajax call? You can directly call URL in your `file_get_contents` function.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function pageContent( $url ) {
    header('Content-type: text/html; charset=EUC-JP');
    echo '<base href="http://brillia.com">';
    echo file_get_contents($url);
}

echo pageContent('http://brillia.com/search/?attribute=1&area=13900,13100,13200,14999,12999,11999');
```